# What JDK should I be using for Android

Tags: java, android

On my old computer all my Android projects target the 1.6 compiler.  I'm transferring them to a new computer and I figured I should use the latest.  Everything in the forums posts says that I should still target 1.6 but those posts were made in 2011.

Should I still be using JDK 1.6?  If so, where can I download it? I read that I should go to
[this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) but there are warnings in red type that this is not recomended for use in production.
(wouldn't it be nice if they would put the JDK download button right next to the ADTBundle download button)

thanks,
Dean

my edit:  After reading the info and discussion below it sounds like I should use JDK 1.7?  Should I also set the project properties to 1.7 compiler?

Comment: Use the Standard Edition Oracle JDK 7 (or JDK 6). JDK 8 is supposed to be backwards-compatible, but for some reason Google only officially recommends JDK7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest JDK8. jdk can work in compliance, eg produce Java 6 compatible byte code.
Also note the SDK supports  Java 7 since build tools 19. Some language features only can be used on API 4.4 and up though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry at all.

You only need a JDK to use the development environment such as Eclipse or Android Studio.

Android does not use a JVM itself. Yes, you program Android using JAVA language, but ultimately your stuff gets executed by the Dalvik Virtual Machine (that is totally different in its internals to a JVM), or better yet, by ART runtime (from Kitkat), that compiles your JAVA bytecode into Native Code at application install time.

So.. Use a reasonably modern JDK that makes your environment run. 1.6 is perfectly fine, maybe 1.7 or 1.8 are more optimized and your IDE will run faster. Also, if you are comfortable with new JAVA language features in 1.8 then go for it, but as I said, 1.6 will run OK too.

Comment: This is not correct. Dx gets Java byte code as input and produces byte code as David format. The Java source is not used by dx nor the application install at all... And the format of the byte code given to dx indeed matters, but that is not a problem with newer jdk as I described in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's the bytecode the thing translated, but unless Java 1.8 produces so terribly optimized bytecode vs. 1.6 (does it??) or the OP desperately neeeds any cool new 1.8 feature for the language (are there?) the bytecode produced by 1.6 is OK in my humble opinion! Maybe I should change "don't worry at all" by "don't worry too much", but I don't think the answer is not correct.

Comment: Yes, i see you corrected your answer. You cannot use Java 1.8 with Android, you have to use 1.7 compliance, since dx cannot understand Java 1.8 class format. It does not matter what JDK you use.
I suggest to always use the latest JDK, unless you have to have strictly compatible JDK with older Java version (not the case with Android).
Also you should not use JDK6 at all, since that is EOL since 2013 February.

Comment: you are right about JDK6 but unfortunately it's a problem for developers using Mac OSX : JDK 7 is not supported by Snow Leopard, and rest of OSX versions are just iOS trash, so a lot of Mac developers still use JDK6 until Apple launches a decent OS ;)

Comment: After reading the info and discussion it sounds like I should use JDK 1.7?  Should I also set the project properties to 1.7 compiler?

Comment: yeah seems the best alternative ;)

Comment: @DeanBlakely you should have used JDK 1.8, and set the project to use 1.7 language level.